# The ith highest jump out of j jumps

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics

I have the following problem from [strategic practice and homework 8](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_8.pdf) of [Stat110](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/home).

> Athletes compete one at a time at the high jump. Let $X_{j}$ be how
> high the jth jumper jumped, with $X_{1}, X_{2},...$ with a continuous
> distribution. We say that the jth jumper set a record if $X_{j}$ is
> greater than all of $X_{j-1}, ....,X_{1}$.
>
> (a) Find the variance of the number of records among the first n
> jumpers (as a sum).

In the solution, it says

> Let $I_j$ be the indicator r.v. for the jth jumper setting a record.
> $I_i$ is independent of $I_j$ for all $i$, $j$ with $i<j$. To see
> this, compute
>
> $P(I_i=I_j=1) = \frac{\binom{j-1}{j-i-1}(j-i-1)!(i-1)!}{j!}$

I don't understand the binomial term in the nominator. It seems to me that this term means to pick any $j-i-1$ jumps out of the remaining $j-1$ (except the jth one), and put them between the jump $i$ and jump $j$. But the problem is we can't pick any jump before jump $i$ and put them there between. This is because then the jump $i$ won't be the highest for the first $i$ jumps (setting a record).

My point is that the jump i must be the largest among the first $i$ jumps and larger than some of the jumps between $i + 1$ and $j - 1$. I was using summation to list cases but it's quickly getting out of hands.

Can anyone give an intuitive explanation to this equation? I also read the explanation of the nominator in the sample solution but it doesn't make sense to me unfortunately.

Comment: Pedantically, this question would be better as the *long jump* with a continuous distribution, since high jump competitions tend to be at discrete heights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a matter of picking a jump before jump $i$ and moving it: you’re just starting with a collection of $j$ jumps, and you want to know in how many ways they can be ordered so that both the one in position $j$ and the one in position $i$ are records. No matter which jumps end up in the first $i$ positions, one of them is the highest, and putting it in position $i$ ensures that that one is a record.

Thus, after you put the best jump in position $j$, you really can pick any $j-i-1$ jumps out of the remaining $j-1$ jumps and put them in positions $i+1$ through $j-1$ in any order; there are $\binom{j-1}{j-i-1}$ ways to pick them and then $(j-i-1)!$ order them in those positions. That leaves $i$ jumps for the first $i$ spots, and you just have to make sure that you put the highest one in position $i$. Once you’ve done that, there are $(i-1)!$ ways to arrange the remaining $i-1$ jumps in the first $i-1$ positions.

Comment: I understand how your argument "position i and j are records" leads to the desired formula. But I'm still confused if that's what the question was asking. It asks to calculate the probability that both jumper i and j sets record, as opposed to position i and j are records. Position j is record  <==> jumper j sets record, obviously. But jumper i sets record -> jumper i could be at position i, i + 1, i + 2, ..., j - 1 since all left slots are smaller -> position i doesn't need to be record. This is my main confusion.

Comment: @Lawerance: The jumpers are identified by the position in which they jumped: jumper $i$ is by definition in position $i$. In other words, jumper $i$ is whichever person made the $i$-th jump. We don’t really care about the **athletes** here: we want the probability that the $j$-th and $i$-th **jumps** are records.

Comment: +1 Just to expand your second paragraph since I had to read it several times:  after you put the best jump in position $j$, you can pick any $j-i-1$ jumps out of the remaining $j-1$ jumps in ${j-1 \choose j-i-1}$ different combinations, and put them in positions $i+1$ through $j-1$ with $(j-i-1)!$ different possible orders ... put the highest remaining jump in position $i$ ... the other $i-1$ jumps can then fill the first $i-1$ positions in $(i-1)!$ different possible orders"

Comment: @Henry: If you had to read it several times, it could probably stand to be expanded, so I’ve done so.

Answer (score 0):

"My point is that the jump i must be the largest among the first i jumps and larger than some of the jumps between i+1 and j−1. I was using summation to list cases but it's quickly getting out of hands."

That is where you got it wrong, the ith jump doesn't need to be higher than any jumps between i+1 and j-1, . The ith jump only needs to be higher than the other i-1 jumps. There can be any other records between i+1 and j-1.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).